# Touch up inside is not working in UIsegment control in xamrin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have used iOS's segmented control in xamrin. I am trying to fire `TouchUp InSide` event but its not working.

Actually I like to find the scenario when user touch the selected segment again. At the moment when user select the selected segment again I want to set the selected segment to unselected state.

What will be best solution for this.

I tried `sgmtPitchnotes.SelectedSegment = 1` but application crashes at this.

Comment: For segment control `value changed` event will be called when you are touching segment to select it.

Comment: i need touch up inside instead of value changed. in my case if i selected one segment user need to click again the selected segment. i fount some solution like unselect the current solution by giving index -1. But it gives crash . 'SelectedSegment = -1;'

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Its very simple after selection we can add this code sgmtPitchnotes.SelectedSegment = 1; it will deselect the current selection . but it giving crash

Comment: @shamnad did you get it or not ??

Answer (score 0):

```
//1.Initialize segment control.
var segmentControl = new UISegmentedControl();
segmentControl.Frame = new CGRect(20,20,280,40);

//2.Insert segment in it
segmentControl.InsertSegment("Segment-One", 0, false);
segmentControl.InsertSegment("Segment-Two", 1, false);
segmentControl.SelectedSegment = 1;

//3.Call back block.
segmentControl.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
var selectedSegmentId = (sender as 
UISegmentedControl).SelectedSegment;
// do something with selectedSegmentId
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
var item = new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
segmentControlEnotes = new UISegmentedControl(item);
segmentControlEnotes.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect((UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 280) / 2, 20, 280, 30);
segmentControlEnotes.SelectedSegment = 0;
segmentControlEnotes.Layer.CornerRadius = 5.0f;
segmentControlEnotes.BackgroundColor = GargiColor.WhiteColor();
segmentControlEnotes.TintColor = GargiColor.PrimaryColor();
```

Touch to Value change

```
segmentControlEnotes.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (((UISegmentedControl)sender).SelectedSegment == 0)
                    // Do Task with Item1 Click
    else if (((UISegmentedControl)sender).SelectedSegment == 1)
                    // Do Task with Item2 Click
    else if (((UISegmentedControl)sender).SelectedSegment == 2)
                    // Do Task with Item3 Click
    else if (((UISegmentedControl)sender).SelectedSegment == 3)
                    // Do Task with Item4 Click
};

View.AddSubview(segmentControlEnotes);
```

If you have any doubt or query then put comment in my answer.

Happy Coding.